# Does not detect when touching the object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Can't detect when I go to the object on the ground. I am sharing information about this situation below.

itemCollector.class

```
    {
        if (other.transform.tag == "Collectable")
        {
            print("Cmon");
            Debug.Log("Come here");

        }
    }
```

[image]
[image]

Doesn't write anything in console section

Comment: With this little to no informations given it's almost impossible to guess what's wrong. How are the physics of both objects set? I see one of them is trigger but what about the other one? Are you using method called on collision with trigger or the general one?

Comment: I want to start the triggering process with tag information, but it doesn't. Do I need to change or add something in my character?

Answer (score 1):

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collision other)
{
    if(other.CompareTag("Collectable")
        {
            Debug.Log("Come Here");
        }
}
```

Try this instead and add the "**Collectable**" Tag to the object.

Answer (score 0):

I think your bottles need a rigidbody component.

Unity has a docs about it: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CollidersOverview.html